# Display radio button in a modal window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a login and registration page using HTML5 and CSS3. I referred this tutorial for the same. 
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/27/login-and-registration-form-with-html5-and-css3/

But I am unable to add radio button in the registration form. Whenever i try to do so, I get a long text field like box instead of radio buttons. However that long box is mutually exclusive.

What changes can I make to add radio buttons.

Comment: Code and screenshot please, preferably a http://jsfiddle.net too

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you followed that tutorial exactly as it is, then I guess your problem is in the CSS part, because the stylesheet they used in there has `#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"])` which applies the the rules to all `input` elements, except checkboxes, inside `#wrapper`. If you want to add radio buttons, you may change this part to:

```
#wrapper input:not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]) {
  ...
}
```